Round or Truncate for Money Operation
operations via decimal (for example a multiplication) are rounded by default (so for example with a decimal with scale of 2, a number 0.126 will be saved 0.13 on the database. By doing operations between currencies (for example multiplications between currencies and wallets, it is better to first truncate without rounds before saving it to the database for having the right result?

it's better to use cents and store money as integers

Where rounding is required, there's 'Banker's Rounding' often used for financial stuff.

Rounding is required for common financial calculations involving interest.  Banker's rounding is a must.

Which database (ignoring the obvious "you usually don't save rounded figures in the database, only round your values when they need to be seen by human eyeballs"), because different databases have different things for that built in.
